# List of workshop upgrades I shouldn't buy in Iron Will mode

Tags: kittens-game

I'm looking for a complete list of all the workshop upgrades that don't benefit me when playing Iron Will mode.

Obviously my goal of Iron Will mode is to get the achievements, so any upgrades after space can be ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list, which might not be complete:

- Mineral hoes
- Iron Hoes
- Mineral Axe
- Iron Axe
- Steel Axe
- Titanium Axe
- Alloy Axe
- Ironwood Huts
- Geodesy?
- Register?
- Mining Drill
- Logistics
- Augmentations
- Astrophysicists
- Factory Optimization
- Telecommunication
- Robotic Assistance
- Factory Robotics

If I forgot something, or if something isn't correct feel free to edit.

Comment: See also this wiki page: http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=Iron+Will